# before insert trigger on Account never fires - why?

Tags: trigger, order-of-execution

My account trigger has heretofore been firing inside this code block

```
if( Trigger.isBefore && (Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isInsert)){    


    ....code ....    

    }
```

I've added a block that should run on before insert, to do some manual changes on record fields before they are committed to the database.  I've added this:

```
if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
    system.debug('***  BEFORE INSERT');
    Map<String,String> kv_country_reverse = new Map<String,String>();
    List<MappingObject__c> ma = new List<MappingObject__c>([SELECT txtKey__c,txtValue__c from MappingObject__c where txtMapName__c = 'ISOCodeToCountry']);  
    for(MappingObject__c t:ma){
        kv_country_reverse.put(t.txtKey__c,t.txtValue__c);
    }  
    for(Account a:Trigger.new){
        // inserted from external application as a ISO shortcode, we look up the correct value in a Map and change it before inserting
        a.Country__c = kv_country_reverse.get(a.Country__c);
    }
}
```

This later block never executes , even though it should be executed first.  The logs doesn't show my debug statement above so nothing is happening.  What am I overseeing?

Comment: Can you post your trigger declaration as well?

Comment: Debug statements are not a fair assessment if something happened. Could have been omitted because of maximum debug log size, or because of your trace flags. You need to check your code coverage to see if it's being covered (you need unit tests).

Comment: You could also setup a custom debug log level where everything is set to none except for Apex which should be set to DEBUG. This will drastically cut down your debug logs

Comment: Hah!  of course it was a PEBKAC,  my trigger statement was
    trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before update, after delete, after update,after insert)   <---  note that this is missing before insert :)  I'm on the right track now

Comment: @akarnid Glad that you were able to figure it out. I had thought so, and thus asked to post the declaration to cross check, if that was indeed the case. You may like to post the correction as an answer so that this question is marked to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the trigger declaration was missing the crucial **before insert**

This is the trigger declaration:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before update, after delete, after update,after insert) {
```

Note that the before insert is missing.  After adding that the code started to execute.